# What’s the right way to create a Webform node when adding a webform?

Tags: 8, nodes, hooks, webforms

I am new to Drupal. I want to create a Webform node when adding a webform. I used the code snippet in https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/webform/webform-cookbook/how-to-automatically-create-a-webform-node-when-adding-a in my .module file. After I submitted a submission, it looks like this hook code snippet didn’t execute, the Webform node didn’t be created. Any thing wrong? What’s the right way to do this?

Here is the code in my mytrymodule.module file:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_webform_insert().
 */
function mytrymodule_webform_insert(\Drupal\webform\WebformInterface $webform)
{

  $node = \Drupal\node\entity\Node::create([
    'type' => 'webform',
    'title' => $webform->label(),
    'webform' => ['target_id' => $webform->id()],
  ]);
  $node->save();

}
```

Comment: How can we know what's wrong with your custom code when you don't show us your custom code and how you implemented it exactly?

Comment: Here is the code in my mytrymodule.module file:

/**
 * Implements hook_webform_insert().
 */
function mytrymodule_webform_insert(\Drupal\webform\WebformInterface $webform)
{

  $node = \Drupal\node\entity\Node::create([
    'type' => 'webform',
    'title' => $webform->label(),
    'webform' => ['target_id' => $webform->id()],
  ]);
  $node->save();

}

Comment: Is your custom module enabled?

Comment: Did you create a webform node type? Or is it provided from a webform submodule?

Comment: I created a webform which has 6 elements on it. What I want to do is after I submit the webform, a node of this webform submission will be created automatically. I found the code snippet at https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/webform/webform-cookbook/how-to-automatically-create-a-webform-node-when-adding-a, and used it in my “.module” file. All other functions/hooks in my “.module” file work fine. However, it looks like this copied code snippet doesn't work, during my debugging, the system didn’t stop at the breakpoint in this hook.
I am new to drupal. Please help!